# How to send daily email to show new registered users - Jetstream - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, database, email, cron, schedule

i am trying to receive a daily email to show me the new registered users from database

i tried "Task Scheduling" but it didn't work for me

is there any tutorial to help me with this?

Comment: What `didn't work`? Do you have any code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

- Create job:

  ```
  php artisan make:job YourSchedule
  ```
- Put your code that send emails to "\app\Jobs\YourSchedule.php" inside method "handle".
- Put this code:

  ```
  $schedule->job(new YourSchedule)->dailyAt('18:00');
  ```

to "\app\Console\Kernel.php" inside method "schedule"

- Add cron task on your server (every minute):

  ```
  php /home/***/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
  ```